# Microsoft Hololens Emulator installation issue

Tags: hyper-v, hololens, hololens-emulator

Unable to install Microsoft Hololens Emulator and throws an error midway:

[image: Hololens Emulator Error]

And the link is of no help as well as it takes to another link showing a solution for "How to enable Hyper-V for the emulator for Windows Phone 8"..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a machine that can handle creating Virtual Machines, So you need an I3 or better and your Bios has to allow VM creation, and you need to be running windows 10 Professional to get access to Hyper-V

Comment: Thanks for the comment Kelso.. Yes, it was the windows version that I was using wrong.. apparently the Hololens Emulator does not work on Windows Home edition.. :)